# Center button into a responsive card

Tags: css, button, centering, card

I am trying to put this button at the center of the card but I am blocked.

```
 <div class="card "   >
                      <img src="/images-portfolio/img-test.jpg"   class="test" />
                      <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Please can someone give me some tips? Thank you
The solution belove it doesn't work to me

[Centering an icon or button inside a responsive card image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628093/centering-an-icon-or-button-inside-a-responsive-card-image)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for?

```css
    .card {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

**Note:** If you want to give other element a unique center, you should wrap them up individually.

```css
    .card {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: yellow;
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="card"   >
    <button>button</button>
</div>
```

You can change the background with value `url('/images-portfolio/img-test.jpg')` to fit your need.

Comment: thanks. I have already tried it but it is not what I want .
Pratically I want a card with a picture as background and a button at the center.

I wrapped the button 
 <div class="card "    >
                        <div class="btn-container">
                             <button>  test</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
What about the picture ? do I have to put it as a background ? 
and will be my css btn-container

Comment: It doesn 't work maybe becouse I am using bootstrap ?
the card is inside col

   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" >   
                    <div class="card">
                        <button>button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: @Val Have you tried to change the class name, like change `.card` to `.my_card`? Maybe there is a name conflict.